# how do in attach a new host to the clariion

Tags: windows-server-2003, storage-area-network, clariion

I 'm a newbie so need lil help on the basics.

I have a new win 2003 server,I need to attach the host to my clariion Cx 700  box.
Can some body walk me through the step by step procedures.
I will appreciate your quick response.

Note: ( I know how to attach Host to the existing storage).

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't mention a connection type - CX's support FC and/or iSCSI - how you connect varies greatly based on this.

Secondly there's no way in hell you should be touching a box of that type unless you know what you're doing or it's a totally non-production box where you can happily blow away any existing config - and I'm really not sure that sounds like it's the case give your urgency. Get someone who knows what they're doing to do the work or go on a course/read-the-manuals.

Sorry to be so negative but I don't want to be responsible to helping you kill a big SAN box.

Comment: Can somebody give me a solution on how to approach.
My connection type is FC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know your setup but generally speaking you need your server to have a FC HBA with fibres of the right kind running to your one or more FC switch/es, they should already be fibred to your CX. You load all the drivers and clustered-file-system tools on the server, you then configure the FC switch/es to see the new FC ports, put them in a VSAN, zone them, activate the updated zoneset, then create a named host on the CX and assigned LUNs, then back on the server you either partition/format the new LUNs or no based on if they're new or not. They're the basics anyway.